# Script PowerShell update SQL Server with csv

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to make a script that allows to update my SQL Server database from several CSV files with different names, example:

```
LOHNSJSHM_details.csv
ZULTNQNIW_details.csv
...
```

Once the data is updated, the file must be deleted automatically.

Here's what I started doing:

```
If ((Get-PSSnapin | where {$_.Name -match "SqlServerCmdletSnapin100"}) -eq $null)
{
  Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
}

If ((Get-PSSnapin | where {$_.Name -match "SqlServerProviderSnapin100"}) -eq $null)
{
  Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100
}

$sql_instance_name = 'ServerSQL01\LAB'
$db_name = 'testdb'

$impcsv = ".\Example.csv"

$data = import-csv $impcsv

$count = 1

foreach($i in $data){

$reference = $i.reference
$quantity = $i.quantite

$query = "UPDATE dbo.F_ARTSTOCK (reference,quantity)
          SET quantity = '$quantity'
          WHERE reference = '$reference'"

$impcsv = invoke-sqlcmd -Database $db_name -Query $query  -serverinstance $sql_instance_name 

write-host "Processing row ..........$count" -foregroundcolor green

$count  = $count + 1

}
```

My file has 2 columns (Reference, Quantity) and I have to update a SAGE table based on the reference withdraw quantities from each line of my CSV

Thank you for help.

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: How should I treat each file and delete it afterwards. Thank you

Comment: you should add that to your post as well ;) assuming you have all the files in one directory you can use `Get-Childitem C:\path\to\files` , loop through your files, execute your sql stuff for everyone of them and afterwards just delete the file with `remove-item`

Comment: Yes all files are in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
If ((Get-PSSnapin | where {$_.Name -match "SqlServerCmdletSnapin100"}) -eq $null)
{
  Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
}

If ((Get-PSSnapin | where {$_.Name -match "SqlServerProviderSnapin100"}) -eq $null)
{
  Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100
}

$sql_instance_name = 'ServerSQL01\LAB'
$db_name = 'testdb'

$csv_folder = 'C:\temp'
$csv_completed_folder = 'C:\done'

# assuming only csv-files you want to import are located in $csv_folder
$csv_files = Get-Childitem -Path $csv_folder -Filter '*.csv'

foreach($file in $csv_files) {
    $impcsv = $file.FullName
    write-host "Processing file ..........$impcsv" -foregroundcolor green
    $data = import-csv $impcsv

    $count = 1

    foreach($i in $data) {

    $reference = $i.reference
    $quantity = $i.quantite

    $query = "UPDATE dbo.F_ARTSTOCK (reference,quantity)
              SET quantity = '$quantity'
              WHERE reference = '$reference'"

    $impcsv = invoke-sqlcmd -Database $db_name -Query $query  -serverinstance $sql_instance_name 

    write-host "Processing row ..........$count" -foregroundcolor green

    $count  = $count + 1

    }
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for returning to what the value is -> $csv_completed_folder ='C:\done' thx

Comment: sorry i didn't finish this thought. instead of deleting imported csv files i would suggest to move the files when done to a specified folder